# Twitter Bootstrap: Modal popup won't fade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fade

I have the following markup using a twitter bootstrap modal plugin:

```
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tabPeople" data-toggle="tab">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabRoles" data-toggle="tab">Roles</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tabPeople">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalEditPerson1">Name</a>
                <div class="modal hide fade in" id="modalEditPerson1">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            ×</button>
                        <h3>
                            Name</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>
                            One fine body…</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Save changes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                   
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabRoles">
                <p>
                    Role stuff here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This brings up a modal, but doesn't fade it as in the demo on this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

**UPDATE**
I have realised that the issue is that it is nested within a .tabbable div which also uses .fade
I've updated the html above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you probably forgot to include the javascript for the animations

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

the transitions.js needs to get included first!

Comment: You were right. I downloaded it from github, so didn't include the plugin, but now I have included it and it still doesn't fade.

Comment: just testet your html and it works fine. Are you shure that you downloaded the correct bootstrap-transition.js  ?

Comment: On this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html I select all the plugins and then click the giant blue button at the bottom.

Comment: I have now removed the relevant html and it works fine. seems to be a problem when it is nested inside a .tabbable element which also fades. Any ideas on how to overcome? Please see the updated html above

Comment: Just a comment that if you are selectively including various css components from bootstrap, you must have the .fade style in stylesheet, too.

Comment: take a look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html - Search for transitions

Answer (score -2):

First place your modal pop outside the body tag.After that comment or remove display property from  class modal-backdrop in bootstrap.css as i have done below

.

```css
modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
  /*display:none;*/
```

```
now write some jquery as i have mentioned below:
```

```js
$("#Yourid").click(function() {

  $('.modal-backdrop fade in').attr("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: 1. You should not place any HTML code outside the body tag.

Comment: 2. Don't modify source bootstrap css files.

Comment: 3. The javascript is not necessary.

Comment: 4. The solution doesn't address the opening post at all (not sure what it is supposed to achieve)

Comment: i was facing issue and didn't found out the solution,so using my knowledge applied this logic and this solution solution worked like charm.There is no rule saying that you cant modified bootstrap css,mostly people modified or overwrite bootstrap css using custom css.

Comment: You are right, there's no rule that says you shouldn't edit third party libraries, but it is a very bad practice to do so. It means that you will never be able to upgrade to a later version of bootstrap without overwriting your customizations. Also, your modifications could negatively affect other Bootstrap functionality since it hasn't gone through Bootstrap's exhaustive internal test suites.